# jquery dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me why my dropdown menu isn't working?  I feel like this is a very simple fix but I'm unable to figure it out.

HTML

```
    <div id="Build" class="dropdown_head col-xs">
        <h1>Build</h1>
        <img src="assets/images/img_1.png">
    </div>    

    <div class="dropdown col-xs">
        <p>Some things are written here</p>

         <img src="assets/images/img_21.png" style="float: right;"> 
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".dropdown_head").on('click'.function(){
    $(".dropdown").slideToggle("slow");

    });
```

});

CSS:

```
.dropdown_head{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

.dropdown{
    font-family: 'Dosis';
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a '.' between `'click'` and `function` when you should have a ',' instead. Change your JavaScript to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown_head").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".dropdown_head").on('click'.function(){
$(".dropdown").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

Looks like a . instead of a , near function()

Answer (score 0):

i have created jsfiddle example for you using your code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".dropdown_head").on('click',function(){

    $(".dropdown").slideToggle("slow");

    });
})
```

you were using . instead of , in this `$(".dropdown_head").on('click',function()` line.

click to see working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/Xuu3K/8/